# Best way to create a regulated 1.95V?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I need a 1.95v for a VDDCORE of a microprocessor I'm using, what would be the best way to get 1.95V from 3.3v? or is a regulator the best way.

Comment: How much current? What accuracy is needed? How much ripple can be tolerated?

Comment: Alex   you must take on board what Photon said otherwise you will get answers that while being "correct" they wont be practical for you.

Comment: Are you sure the microprocessor can't provide the regulation for you from VDD, because a lot of them will?

Comment: I'm not sure, it says VDDCORE requires 1.95V. if it could surly they wouldn't need the VDDCORE pin?

Comment: Usually you'd put a cap on that pin even if it's internally regulated. Link the data sheet for us to see.

Comment: http://www.atmel.com/images/6120s.pdf

Comment: Yes, you are right. It does have a 1.8V regulator. so I would cap VDDIO and provide power only to VDDIN? what is done with VDDOUT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary to provide the `VDDCORE` voltage externally. `VDDOUT` can provide the typical 1.8VDC for the core, so you can just connect this to `VDDCORE` and `VDDPLL` with external decoupling caps (described in section 5.3).

Section 5, and specifically 5.3 provides the info you're looking for:

> VDDCORE pins. They power the logic of the device; voltage ranges from 1.65V to 1.95V, 1.8V typical. It can be
>   connected to the VDDOUT pin with decoupling capacitor. VDDCORE is required for the device, including its
>   embedded Flash, to operate correctly.
>
> Voltage Regulator
>   The SAM7X512/256/128 embeds a voltage regulator that is managed by the System Controller.
>   In Normal Mode, the voltage regulator consumes less than 100 μA static current and draws 100 mA of output current.
>   The voltage regulator also has a Low-power Mode. In this mode, it consumes less than 25 μA static current and draws 1
>   mA of output current.
>   Adequate output supply decoupling is mandatory for VDDOUT to reduce ripple and avoid oscillations. The best way to
>   achieve this is to use two capacitors in parallel: one external 470 pF (or 1 nF) NPO capacitor should be connected
>   between VDDOUT and GND as close to the chip as possible. One external 2.2 μF (or 3.3 μF) X7R capacitor should be
>   connected between VDDOUT and GND.
>   Adequate input supply decoupling is mandatory for VDDIN in order to improve startup stability and reduce source voltage
>   drop. The input decoupling capacitor should be placed close to the chip. For example, two capacitors can be used in
>   parallel: 100 nF NPO and 4.7 μF X7R

And Section 5.4 shows a typical powering scheme.

Answer (score 2):

A regulator is pretty much the only way.  Depending on how much current you need you could use an LDO or a switching converter.  Any other approach would probably not give you a stable and accurate enough voltage.